# Why is my ellipse not appearing?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot an ellipse in matplotlib, but when I execute this code:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

fig = Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.add_artist(Ellipse(xy=(1, 1), width=2, height=2, facecolor='g', edgecolor='k', alpha=.1))
show()
```

nothing happens at all.  I get no figure, much less an ellipse.

What gives?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `figure` must be spelled in lower case. You want to [create a figure](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.0/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure) and display it. If you use the Uppercase spelling, you instantiate the [`Figure` class](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.0/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure).

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.add_artist(Ellipse(xy=(1, 1), width=2, height=2, facecolor='g', edgecolor='k', alpha=.1))
plt.show()
```

Comment: whaaaaat?  `Figure` works just fine for every plot I've made so far; isn't it a class?  What's the difference, then, between `Figure` and `figure`?

Comment: and even with the lowercase spelling of `figure`, my problem persists, at least in the interactive shell.  In an ipython-notebook, this seems to work.

Comment: What version of mpl and python do you use? It works with mpl 1.2 and python 2.7 on my machine. What backend do you use?

Comment: I edited my post above, but I'm using python 2.7 latest and (I believe) the development version of mpl.  How would I check the mpl version?

Comment: I added links to the documentation, which should be clear about the difference of `figure` and `Figure`.

Comment: You get the version by checking the variable `matplotlib.__version__`

Comment: my version is 1.3.x.  In any case, thank you for the links; this cleared up a completely unrelated issue whereby the `figsize` keyword wasn't being recognized.  As for the present issue, as long as it works in the ipython-notebook (which it does), I'm happy.  I"ll accept your answer in 4 minutes =)

Comment: It could be that you're using a matplotlib backend, which doesn't support interactive display on the screen, but can only write figures to files and therefore `plt.show` doesn't do anything.