# ellipse not showing up - python matplotib

Tags: python, matplotlib, ellipse

I am trying to plot an ellipse.

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ellipse = Ellipse(mean1L, ellipse_x, ellipse_y, angle=theta)
ax.add_artist(ellipse)
plt.show()
```

Every argument seems fine, but it isn't showing up.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained example? Your code uses variables defined elsewhere.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408447/why-is-my-ellipse-not-appearing

Answer (score 4):

The ellipse is outside of the axis limits.

Instead of `ax.add_artist(ellipse)` you would rather use

```
ax.add_patch(ellipse)
```

to be able to adjust the axis limits easily to the added patch.
This will allow to later call `ax.autoscale_view()` to automatically adjust the axis limits.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
ax = plt.subplot(111)

ellipse = Ellipse((2,2), 1,1.5 , angle=60)
ax.add_patch(ellipse)

ax.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

[image]